# How to create a realtime event trigger based on database update using NodeJS and Socket.io?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, node.js, socket.io

I want to implement a realtime update. I am using MySQL as my database and in my process I already displayed the data from my database in my page. My problem is for example I edited something on the database is it possible for `Nodejs` and `Socket.io` to update automatically the view in my page?

Here's my code so far:

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mysql = require('mysql');
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
var jQuery = require('jQuery');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'node'    
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/bower_components', express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

connection.connect();

function loadList(callback) {

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM inventory', function(err, rows, fields){

        if(err) return callback(err);

        return callback(null,rows);

    });

}

io.on('connection', function(socket){

    console.log('A user is connected!!');

    loadList(function(err, product_list){
        socket.emit('inventory list', {list: product_list});
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('user disconnected!');
    });

});

http.listen(8000, function() {
    console.log('Listening on ' + port);
});
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="container">

    <h4>Stock List</h4>

    <table id="list" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Product Name</td>
                <td>Price</td>
                <td>Quantity</td>
                <td>Status</td>
                <td>Date Added</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    try {
        var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8000');
        //console.log(socket);
    }catch(e) {
        console.log('ERROR OCURRED: ' + e);
    }

    if(socket !== undefined) {
        socket.on('inventory list', function(data){

            var html = '';

            $.each(data.list, function(k, v){
                html += '<tr>';
                html += '<td>' + v.inventory_id + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + v.product_name + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + v.price + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + v.quantity + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + v.status + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + v.date_added + '</td>';
                html += '<td><a href="">Edit</a></td>';
                html += '</tr>';
            });

            $('#list tbody').html(html);

        });
    }

</script>
```

Can you provide me a good example for this?
I also found this library:
https://github.com/techpines/express.io

It looks good but there's no integration with MySQL.

Comment: Are you the one who is updating the said database? If you are, you could save yourself a pretty complex task by firing the socket event on that database update

Comment: Yes I manually edited the data straight from mysql table. Can you give me some reference about socket event based on database update?

Comment: You could check database periodically and send only different data when occurs.

Comment: Wondering if you found a solution to this as I'm having the exact same problem...